# How can I retry a try-catch after I catch an IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, android, while-loop, try-catch, android-mediaplayer

I know that this question is asked before but I couldn't implemented it to my code. How can I retry the try-catch block again if I catch?

```
if(mediaPlayer!=null){

            try {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                songEnded = 0;
            } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                // media player is not initialized
                
                //TRY AGAIN

            }


        }
```

Comment: You could 1. declare an (IllegalState)Exception variable. 2. Enclose the try/catch in a `do` loop. 3. Assign your exception var. to a) `null` after 'songEnded = 0;` or in the catch block, to b) the caught exception. 4. Finalise it with a `while (tmpException != null);`

Comment: ..this loop would repeat, until exception==null ... alternative variable type: boolean(!/byte,short,..;)

Comment: ..but in case you want to retry it only once (n-times): you can repeat the try catch *within* the (outer/first) `catch` (define a (throwing/catching) method for this , to minimimize code repetition an for `n` retries: limit the above loop by `n`, and invoke the (inner) function instead... )

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to wrap it in a while loop, and add a condition in the while loop that checks whether the media player has started or not.

E.g.:

```
    void playMediaPlayer() {

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        
        while (!mediaPlayer.initialized) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.initialized = true;
            } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
                // optionally wait some time before trying again
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static class MediaPlayer {
        
        boolean initialized = false;
        
        public void start() throws IllegalStateException{
        }
    }
```